# Funcionamento do group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql, query, group-concat

Tenho algumas dúvidas relacionadas ao uso de `group_concat`, mais especificamente por parte de desempenho. Quando se usa `group_concat` não se consegue usar `limit`.

```
// a query retorna todos os ID's
select group_concat( id ) from table limit 5

// pelo que eu vi, a solução seria usar substring_index para pegar a quantidade X
substring_index( group_concat( id ) , ',' , 5 )
```

Queria saber se `group_concat` prejudica de alguma forma o desempenho, já que ele retorna todos os *ID's* - como no exemplo acima - e o motivo de `limit` ser ignorado na query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O group_concat concatena uma sequencia de campos de acordo com a sua query e grupo definidos.

No seu exemplo, não há um grupo definido, portanto, ele irá concatenar todos os *id* da tabela *table*.
A cláusula *limit* é aplicada **após** o *select* ser executado.
Ou seja, o MySQL/MariaDB irá percorrer toda a tabela, concatenar todos os campos, e trazer os 5 primeiros grupos (no caso, haverá apenas 1).

Pelo que você descreveu, não é isto que você deseja.

O teu problema com performance deve ser devido ao full-table scan provocado.

Dentre algumas soluções, você pode:

- Utilizar uma cláusula where
- Utilizar uma subselect com o limit, e aplicar o group_concat após.

Apenas salientando que, por padrão, o group_concat tem um limite de tamanho (1024 bytes).

Você deve ajustar este limite antes de executar a query que traz o group_concat com (aumentar para 1M):

```
set @@group_concat_max_len=1048576;
```

Lembrando que este valor é válido apenas enquanto durar sua sessão.