# Inner join repetindo dados

Tags: php, mysql

Utilizo uma consulta usando o inner join, só que o problema é que ele me duplica os resultados tenho uma tabela no mysql que se chama `produtos_destaque` onde o `id_produtoDestaque` é chave estrangeira na tabela beneficios. O meu problema é que um produto pode ter até 5 beneficios e na hora de mostra os dados no php todos os produtos que tem mais de 1 beneficio é duplicado

```
SELECT produto_destaque.*,beneficio.beneficio 
FROM produto_destaque 
INNER JOIN beneficio ON produto_destaque.id_produtoDestaque = beneficio.id_produtoDestaque
```

ja tentei utilizar o `group by` e não tive sucesso. Como poderia resolver esse problema ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esse é o retorno que tenha da minha consulta com o inner

Comment: Quando tiver mais de um, qual dos benefícios é pra retornar?

Comment: Não tem como  pegar o produto só uma vez, e tudo que estiver relacionado ao produto. Uma query vai sempre retornar uma tabela. `GROUP BY` funciona só com números, pois te permite compilar valores em uma única linha através de operações matemáticas.

Comment: Me expressei mal, ele deve retornar todos os beneficios, mas sem repetir o nome do produto,descricao e foto

Comment: Join é pra juntar lado A com lado B, como é que vai voltar um benefício sem produto? Não tem muita lógica a pergunta então.

Comment: entao eu terei que usar dois selects ?

Comment: É uma das saídas. Faça um pegando os produtos, e um outro pegando os beneficios, e junte no PHP.

Comment: A estrutura que você espera é tipo um nó relacionado aos valores, como disse, SQL só retorna um grid, uma tabela.

Comment: Uma solução BEM simples é você pegar primeiro a lista de produtos, e guardar num _array_ (se nao for gigantesca, claro). Aí ao pegar cada linha, você acrescenta um membro extra na linha chamado beneficios, com array vazio. Em seguida faz um select nos beneficios, e já vai pondo no array do produto certo pelo id do relacionamento.

Comment: coloquei uma foto de como meu inner retorna

Comment: Talves isso aqui resolva: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field. Ao contrário do que falei, parece que da para utilizar operação de concatenação de texto com `GROUP BY`. DOC: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 5):

O `JOIN` relaciona duas tabelas, relacionando os dados como se fosse tudo parte de uma tabelona só, composta pelas duas.

Aqui tem uma explicação boa de como funciona:

> [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70)

### Se for precisar de vários campos de `beneficios`

No seu caso, se quer todos os benefícios, mas uma vez só cada produto, pode fazer esta organização pelo PHP, algo mais ou menos assim:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) die( $mysqli->connect_error );

// usei o * por nao saber seus campos. na pratica use só os que precisa
$mysqli->query( 'SELECT * FROM produto_destaque' ) or die($mysqli->error);
$res = $mysqli->use_result();

// criamos um array vazio para guardar os produtos
$produtos = array();
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    // em cada produto acrescentamos um lugar para os beneficios
    $row['beneficios'] = array();
    // e guardamos a linha em $produtos
    $produtos[$row['id_produtoDestaque']] = $row;
}
$res->free();

// em seguida, vamos pegar todos os beneficios
$mysqli->query( 'SELECT * FROM beneficio' ) or die($mysqli->error);
$res = $mysqli->use_result();

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    // agora guardamos o beneficio na chave 'beneficios' do 
    // produto correspondente, que criamos no SELECT anterior
    $produtos[$row['id_produtoDestaque']]['beneficios'][] = $row;
}
$res->free();

// aqui é só para conferir o resultado
print_r( $produtos );
```

### Se for precisar de um campo só

Se for precisar de um campo só dos benefícios, como comentou o colega @mauhumor, pode usar o `group_concat`:

```
SELECT     produto_destaque.*, GROUP_CONCAT( beneficio.beneficio )
FROM       produto_destaque 
INNER JOIN beneficio
           ON produto_destaque.id_produtoDestaque = beneficio.id_produtoDestaque
GROUP BY   produto_destaque.id_produtoDestaque
```

> [Funcionamento do group_concat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81187/70)

Comment: Com o uso do `group_concat` funcionou, porém ele me retorna os resutados assim  `- Sensação de saciedade, efeito parecido a sibutramina, Acelera a plenitude gástrica, Auxilia na manutenção do peso, Aumenta a queima de gordura, Reduz gordura visceral.` Teria como ele retornar assim só que um em baixo do outro :
`- Sensação de saciedade, 
- efeito parecido a sibutramina, 
- Acelera a plenitude gástrica,
- Auxilia na manutenção do peso, 
- Aumenta a queima de gordura, 
- Reduz gordura visceral.`

Comment: @fabricio sim, veja no link no bloco amarelo para mais detalhes da função; Se especificar o segundo parametro, pode por o que quiser no lugar da virgula (por exemplo, um ponto e virgula e em seguida a quebra de linha). O separador padrão é a vírgula, mas você pode por a string que quiser.