# Agrupar resultados numa consulta com INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

poderiam me auxiliar nessa? Tenho duas tabelas "tb_alunos" e "tb_cursos". Após comandar um INNER JOIN conforme o código:

```
SELECT tb_alunos.nome, tb_cursos.materia
FROM tb_alunos
INNER JOIN tb_cursos
ON tb_alunos.id = tb_cursos.id
ORDER BY tb_alunos.nome
```

Obtenho a tabela:

[Tabela Atual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRqKW.png)

QUal seria a solução para juntar as linhas, dessa forma:

[Tabela esperada](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLZT9.png)

Muitissimo obrigado.

Comment: Documentação mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat - resposta de exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/176936/3635

Comment: Funcioonou demais aqui! Já tinha tentado o "GROUP_CONCAT", mas faltou o GROUP BY. Muito obrigado!